# Send an extra variable by post in bootstrap-fileinput

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

How to send an extra variable to php by post in [bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput).

I have added the css and js in my web,and here is my html:

```
<input name="uploadfile" id="input-id" type="file" multiple class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
```

This is my script:

```
$('#input-id').fileinput({
    language: 'en',
    uploadUrl: 'upload?path=/',
    maxFileCount: 5,
    // allowedFileExtensions : ['any'],
});
```

it's the variable
`path = '/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `uploadExtraData`, as in:

```
$('#input-id').fileinput({
    language: 'en',
    uploadUrl: 'upload?path=/',
    maxFileCount: 5,
    // allowedFileExtensions : ['any'],
    uploadExtraData: function() {
        return {
            foo: "bar"
        };
    }
});
```